# how to create instance from an inmutable objects?

Tags: java, immutability, instantiation

I am trying to create a new instance from an inmutable object. In this case, is a List, and i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:364)
    at com.example.movies.domain.transformer.DomainEntityTransformer.transformEntityArray(DomainEntityTransformer.java:32)
    at com.example.movies.domain.service.client.impl.ClientServiceImpl.getClients(ClientServiceImpl.java:58)
    at com.example.movies.service.controller.ClientController.getClients(ClientController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

This is the transformer class where the exception has been thrown

```
public Collection<DOM> transformEntityArray(Collection<ENT> iterable) {
    try {
        Collection<DOM> transformed = iterable.getClass().newInstance();
        Iterator<ENT> iterator = iterable.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ENT element = iterator.next();
            transformed.add(this.transformEntity(element));
        }
        return transformed;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the implementation

```
Page<Client> clientsEntity = this.dao.findAll(new PageRequest(offset, limit));
List<ClientDomain> clientsDomain = (List<ClientDomain>) this.transformer.transformEntityArray(clientsEntity
    .getContent());
```

Do you know people how to fix it? Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we do

```
transformed = new ArrayList<>();
```

And generally (even though it makes no sense in your case), you can create inmutable objects by calling the appropriete constructor with all the necessary parameters to set the state of the object.

In your case it is
`UnmodifiableRandomAccessList(List<? extends E> list)`,
which you can access by `getClass().getConstructor...`
(and you will still need the temporary ArrayList to store your results).

but you cannot provide generic solution that will work for any input collection, as you need to know which contructor to call == know the java code of actual call parameters.
Which renders using Genereirc and Interfaces completely pointless.

So just create the Arbitrary chosen collection (ArrayList) as it does not affect further parts of your code.

Comment: Yes,we do! Do you think this needs to be the part of an answer? ;)

Comment: it felt too short without it

Comment: But that way i'm limiting the return class just to a ArrayList. I want to create an instance of the Collections class i am recieving by parameter so that way i could return the same collection class and not always an ArrayList

Comment: You are returning Collection not ArrayList. The code after the call to transformEntityArray will know only that it is a collection so you are limiting to a collection. And as you are just discovered you cannot return the same collection class in all the instances. If you want to have particular collection type, bound it wiht your method declaration. Actually your code even does casting to the List instead of having the transforamtion method declared as such.

Comment: @user2601512 I described for you how you can create immutable object. But it really does not make sense. Please think about interfaces in java and why they are being used.

Comment: One more tip. Do not catch the exception and throw null instead. This null will propaagete through your code and may raise the nullpointer exception much further in your code, but you will not see where the null  came from